# Rounding down to 2 decimals in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on this slider through the use of a javascript function however the output shows a 12 decimal places. I'd like for it to be reduced to 2. I'm super new this javascript so I'd greatly appreciate your help implementing your solution.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

function moveSlider(e){
    var pos   = $(e.currentTarget).offset()
,   posX  = e.pageX - pos.left
,   value = posX*10000/$(e.currentTarget).outerWidth();

if(posX >= 0 && posX <= $(e.currentTarget).outerWidth()){

    $('.slider > .progress').css('width', posX+'px');
    $('.slider > .indicator').css('left', posX+'px');

    $('#valueSlider').val(value);

   }
 } 



 $('.slider').on('mousedown', function(e){

    moveSlider(e);

    $(this).on('mousemove', function(e){
       moveSlider(e); 
    });

 }).on('mouseup', function(){
    $(this).off('mousemove');
    });

 });
```

Comment: try `.toFixed(2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var myVar = 5.2235;
  var res = myVar.toFixed(2);
```

try it